Can a low breaking capacity cause a fuse to blow?
A fuse in one of my speaker (SRT 212) broke due to what we think was a disfunctional power strip (after that, the speaker would not turn on anymore).
The reference of the fuse written on the board inside the speaker is, precisely, T2.5AH 250V (100-240V~ 50-60Hz 75W)
So I decided to buy a new fuse that meet these requirements. I did not find a fuse that also had the "H" (which stands for High Breaking Capacity apparently) so I bought a T2.5A 250V fuse.
This one to be exact : https://www.galaxus.ch/fr/s4/product/eska-5x20mm-t-25a-250v-522521-fusible-fin-a-action-retardee-siba-179120-microfusible-250-a-paresseux-23237791?supplier=406802
I replaced it and plugged the speaker but this new fuse blew up instantly (there was a flash and the wire inside it broke).
So I have a a few questions :

How could the fuse break if it was meeting the requirements ?
Could a different breaking capacity be the cause for this ?
Why can't I find a T2.5AH 250V fuse ? (I live in Switzerland)
Could some other part of the speaker be broken, creating a faulty current that breaks the fuse ?

I'm kind of a rookie in electronics so I will edit my question if you need more informations.
Thanks in advance.

The fuse died because something downstream of the fuse (i.e. inside the speaker) draw too much current through the fuse. This has little-to-nothing to do with the power strip you plugged it into.


It can't - so the device is broken and now blows up fuses.

No, because breaking ability means when it breaks due to overcurrent, how much short circuit current the fuse can reliably break - For example a standard fuse might be good for 100A and high rated fuse up to 1000A. A 100A rated fuse would blow and keep conducting 1000A if you had 1000A short circuit current.

Good question. We don't know how much you have searched and why can't you find one. These generally are not used in consumer equipment, and thus it is unknown why your speakers had high breakage rated fuse. Also a good question is, does it even require one or will standard be just fine. Your manual, service manual, or something else must indicate a suitable fuse type. Check carefully if it requires a high breakage fuse or will a normal do.

As per #1, there definitely is a fault that blows up fuses until you fix the fault.



Also, the manual says the fuse is not user serviceable. Why it is so is not known, maybe because often people replace it with wrong type, or that a blown fuse basically means there is a fault that does not go away without repair.


How could the fuse break if it was meeting the requirements ?

Was it really meeting the requirements? Fuses have time*current^2 products that govern how fast they blow for various overload and short circuit durations.

Could a different breaking capacity be the cause for this ?

Yes. Undersizing the the fuse will increase the probability the fuse will blow, even under normal operating conditions. Oversizing the fuse will reduce the chances of false tripping (not recomended). However, undersizing the fuse will reduce the the protection the fuse was intended to maintain.

Why can't I find a T2.5AH 250V fuse ? (I live in Switzerland)

I know nothing about the Switzerland fuse market. But You could try using a fuse with a longer time delay. In the US this would be called "slo-blow" or "time-delay" or sometimes "dual-element" with the same rating (2.5A).

Could some other part of the speaker be broken, creating a faulty
current that breaks the fuse ?

Absolutely. And this is exactly the kind of event the fuse is intended to prevent. So the fuse is working properly in this case.
So, if the fuse is blowing instantly at start up due to a large surge (from the passives - caps and transformers), you need a longer time-delay fuse. You are likely using a "fast-blow" fuse. That is assuming there is nothing actually wrong.
If the fuse blows after several minutes to an hour after warming up, you may have a problem with the actual amplifier circuitry. In this case you are SOL.
If you can't find the equivalent replacement fuse, what I would do, is use a larger fuse (temporarily) to see if the amplifier is at least operational. If you have a dead short, even the larger fuse will open instantly. If it holds, and the amplifier works, You have an overload problem. I don't recommend this approach unless you really know what you are doing as you can further damage the equipment and possibly cause smoke/fire. But it will give you further information about the situation.

But T already means slow-blow. The question is about high current breaking ability.
